# Resque worker foreman failing to start workers

Tags: ruby, resque, foreman

I have a foreman script starting up some workers on a standalone ruby app. Here's the script

**Foreman script**
`worker: bundle exec rake resque:work BACKGROUND=true QUEUE=image VERBOSE=true`

When I run the script this is the output I get.

```
$ foreman start
22:00:38 worker.1 | started with pid 882
22:00:38 worker.1 | exited with code 0
22:00:38 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

The process seems to have exited but when I look at the `ps -eaf | grep resque` log it shows a resque worker running with pid 884. I've tested this and its always a pid +2 than the original.

When I run the bundle exec command straight from the terminal without foreman, the command executes just fine. Is there anything I'm missing with the foreman script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently, when running BACKGROUND=true the resque workers get daemonized and therefore the original pid gets deleted and a new one gets spanwed as an orphan process for the worker.

Still, there is an issue when creating 2 background workers with foreman because once one of the workers gets daemonized, foreman will end all processes and only one daemonized worker will be created instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

You should not daemonize the workers with foreman - foreman needs to have all the processes running in the foreground. If you want multiple workers, simply use something like this:

```
image_worker: bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=image VERBOSE=true
other_worker: bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=other VERBOSE=true
```

To start multiple workers on the same queue:

```
foreman start -m image_worker=2
```